# Vagrant Windows 7 Virtual Box interface inaccesible

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vagrant

I have been setting up virtual boxes for testing and development for our team. Creating the Virtualbox Windows 7 Internet Explorer 8 instance went fine. When I tried to package it into a Vagrant .box file and re-instantiate it as a server is where I have experienced issues.

After some research regarding the Windows vb never fully starting I found a Vagrant plugin that allows it to work with most versions of Windows: https://github.com/WinRb/vagrant-windows

After completing the plugin install and configuration the Windows vb will start completely but sits at the login screen indefinitely, without any GUI window to interface with only the VB window. see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm0LH.png

Comment: I thought I posted this question earlier today and then found out the answer just now. Since this may be helpful for others I decided to post the question and then answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
   vb.gui = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It was stuck at the Windows login screen. If you start the VM in headless mode (default used by Vagrant), you'll have to configure automatical log on for Windows, refer to => http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx

Otherwise, as you already know, you can use the vbox gui and login from the console;-)

Comment: While somewhat useful this would not cause virtualbox to give me a window to actually do anythign in, the GUI has to be booted with the correct configuration in the Vagrantfile. See my answer from the Vagrant for windows plugin creator.